Why is o used for hydroxy groups in IUPAC naming instead of saying 2-hydroxy

For this question, i marked compound II correct as 2-methylbenzaldehyde and got the question correct, but for compound I, i marked it wrong and suggested the name to be 2-hydroxybenzaldehyde. I got the question wrong.
Why don't these 2 follow the same pattern in naming? Why is I named as o-hydroxybenzaldehyde? And if the hydroxy group was situated one C to the left, would it then be correct to say 3-hydroxybenzaldehyde? Or would it still be o-hydroxybenzaldehyde?

o stands for ortho.

"o" isn't for hydroxy but for ortho. 2-hydroxy should have been an acceptable alternative.

This use of o, m, and p is strongly discouraged and is not used in preferred IUPAC names.

Consider the two forms as dialects.
With

ortho (or o) you describe a 1,2
meta (or m) you describe a 1,3
para (or p) you describe a 1,4 relationship

of two substituents of for instance a benzene ring.  Hence 2-methylbenzaldehyde describes the same structure as does o-methylbenzaldehyde.  However, the number scheme is easily extendable to the presence of more than two substituents (and hence more general applicable) than ortho, meta, para constrained to two.
Ortho, meta, para; and ipso, meso, peri however equally are used to describe the position of an entrant substituent relative to an other, already present one, in reaction mechanisms.  I think their use here will continue for quite some time.
